# Variance of non-biased estimator $S^2$ for $\theta$ in $X \sim \text{Poisson}(\theta)$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I am having some trouble finding the $\text{Var}(S^2)$.

I am using this formula: $$\text{Var}(S^2)=\frac{1}{n}\left[\mu_4-\frac{n-3}{n-1}\sigma^4\right]$$

With, $$\mu_4=E\left[(x-\mu)^4\right]$$

To calculate $\mu4$, I have used the central moment generating function: $$M_{x}^{c}(t)=E\left[e^{t(x-\mu)}\right]=\exp{\{-\theta t\}}\exp{\{\theta(e^t-1)\}}=\exp{\{\theta(e^t-1)-\theta t\}}$$

So, according to Wolfram Alpha, $$\mu_4=\frac{\partial^4 M_{x}^{c}(t)}{\partial t^4}\Bigr|_{t=0}=\theta(3\theta+1)$$

Therefore, $$\text{Var}(S^2)=\frac{1}{n}\left[3\theta^2+\theta-\frac{n-3}{n-1}\theta^2\right]=\frac{1}{n}\left[\frac{2n\theta^2+n\theta-\theta}{n-1}\right]$$

But I know that the variance should be: $$\text{Var}(S^2)=\frac{\theta}{n}+\frac{2\theta^2}{n-1}$$

Am I missing something in the process?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Expand what you have.

Comment: I have already tried that, but I don't reach the same expression.

Comment: In that case I wish you best of luck in your future endeavors.

Comment: An unbiased estimator for the variance $\lambda$ of a Poisson distribution is $\hat\lambda = \bar X.$ For a Poisson distribution $\mu = \sigma^2 =\lambda.$ // Either you're making this needlessly complicated or you've been asked to do something that is not obvious from your Question. // in R, we can generate a million observations from POIS(5): code `set.seed(2021); x = rpois(10^6, 5); mean(x); var(x)` returns  $5.001814$ and
$5.00392;$ two place accuracy.

Comment: Actually, the purpose of the exercise I am solving is to compare these two estimators $(S^2 \text{and} \bar{X})$ for $\theta$, showing that $\bar{X}$ has a lower variance, which is kinda obvious, given that $\text{Var}(\bar{X})=\text{LI}$. However, I need to find the variance for $S^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\text{var}(S^2) &= \frac{1}{n}\left( \frac{2n\theta^2 + n\theta - \theta}{n -1} \right)\\
&= \frac{2n}{n(n - 1)}\theta^2 + \frac{n - 1}{n(n - 1)}\theta \\
&= \frac{2}{n - 1}\theta^2 + \frac{1}{n}\theta.
\end{align*}
I have no doubt you can take it from there, comparing this with your desired solution.